# how can I build a website which have the user input like http://mathway.com?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, latex, maple, mathml

I'm a newbie Website development. I'm building a website which solves Math problems by using ASP.NET and Maple. I have a problem that how can I build a website which have the user input like http://mathway.com ? and how to process that input? I've searched on many topics but I have not found the way to solve this problem. Can I use javacrpipt, CSS or something like that to build my website? Someone help me, pls! Sorry for any English error.

Answer (score 0):

About the url, you are talking about domaine name : 
take a look at : 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System

And yes, you can use html and the js: it's like your Front Office, a Graphical User Interface that will let you interact with your asp.net remote data . 
And website coding is like another big adventure. Do you have any notions to begin, a specific target ?

Comment: thanks SamiX,
I just learn to code web to complete my project in college. Can you tell me step by step to solve my problem? I'm just a newbie..

Comment: check this complete example with ASP.NET webservice implementation and consuming. This should give an idea about all the interactions and the way to proceed :
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/calling-the-Asp-Net-web-api-with-jquery-and-javascript/